# Creating a Power BI table using a column in a different table

Tags: powerbi, path, dax, powerquery

I have a Power BI table containing a column of Folder Paths.

The requirement is to return the output from Folder.Files for each row of the column (of folder paths)

I can hard code the Folder Path and return the values using a hard coded path such as

`= Folder.Files("C:\Users\rj3838\PrimarySites")`

However, I wish to get the Path from a column in a table and process all the paths in the column.

The output of these individual queries should create a new table containing all the fields returned from `Folder.Files`.

At present the manipulation/processing is using M query as it's at the first stage but could be using DAX, I'm struggling with either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powerquery / M, take the table that includes the folder paths

Add column ... custom column ...

```
= Folder.Files([PutNameOfYourFolderPathColumnHere])
```

Then use the arrow atop the new column to expand the rows

You can remove columns and filter this to make a new table

Comment: Works as required - Thanks. For the next person who may be using this, the file path returned can be broken up using 'split column' -> by Delimiter ->select Delimiter as '\' -> 'Right-most delimiter' then repeat as necessary to get the path components.